# What is state of port B when port A of FT2232H is in sync. FT245 mode?

Tags: ftdi, spartan

I am designing Spartan 6 dev board with FT2232H interface, and I would like to use FT2232H to program  AT45 flash with bitstream and then switch FTDI to FT245 mode and use 60MHz clock of 2232H as main clock of Spartan.

As far as programming AT45 flash I got it covered, I will hold Spartan in High-Z by holding Spartan's PROGRAM_B low with FT2232H (which should be possible by using GPIO pins of port B in SPI mode).

Then I would release PROGRAM_B to high (I have 4.7k pull-up on PROGRAM_B pin) and switch FT2232H to FT245 mode which should make Spartan load it's bitstream from flash and initialize with 60MHz coming from FTDI.

And this last step is the thing I am not certain about. Will switching to FT245 mode leave pins of port B of FTDI in High-Z or in last state? Will Spartan wait for FTDI to put out FT245 60MHz clock?

This picture shows diagram of current connection (it's not polished yet because since it's BGA package I was trying to use optimal pins, but should be clear enough, for note 60MHz clock on pin 32 of ftdi is connected to GCLK0 of Spartan) [image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40318793/spartanAndFtdi.png]

Comment: Have you tried just e-mailing FTDI? I'd imagine they'd be happy to help-out.

Comment: The are actually tristated (I have managed to get dev board for FT2232H from on my university) the device is fully working - if someone were interested here are all design and source files https://github.com/josko7452/qwave-project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that the pins would be tristated. In order to setup sync ft245 you must first set both channels up as async ft245. Given that you are likely not planning on setting up the sync mode while a write strobe is active, the last state is tristated too. Once the resources are locked up by the sync channel, I wouldn't expect the IC to respond after that.

Someone who has tried it may be able to confirm, but given how I expect ftdi devices to behave, I'd be surprised if that isn't the behavior you see.

Comment: If they were tristated it would be ideal situation. It would allow Spartan to load it's bitstream given that SPI bus will not be interfered by FTDI. Only thing is wether Spartan's DCMs would be able to lock in on FT245 clock.